# How to convert from JSON to XML

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to convert some JSON to XML with [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2xml), I need to do that in order to send some data to the Database in a post request I am working on.

This is what `req.body` returns

```
{ DealerName: 'amrcl',
  CardId: '123',
  Nickname: 'mkm123',
  Picture: 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/',
  Active: '1',
  LegalId: '1',
  TypeId: '1'
}
```

is dynamic data. Let me show you the code

```
export default function (req, res) {
  try {
    const connection = new sql.Connection(spConfig, function spConnection (errSpConnection) {
      const request = connection.request();
      if (errSpConnection) {
        res.status(401);
      }
      request.input('Dealer_Param', sql.VarChar(1000), req.body);
      request.input('param_IS_DEBUG', sql.Bit, null);
      request.output('output_IS_SUCCESSFUL', sql.Bit);
      request.output('output_STATUS', sql.VarChar(500));
      request.execute('[mydbo].[StoredProcedure]', function spExecution (errSpExecution, dataset) {
        connection.close();
        if (errSpExecution) {
          res.status(401);
        } else {
          if (request.parameters.output_IS_SUCCESSFUL.value) {
            res.status(200).json({
              success : 'New dealer successfully inserted.',
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

that is for Stored Procedure method which is with the [mssql module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql).

As you see the code above, there is a failure error, because in `request.input('Dealer_Param', sql.VarChar(1000), req.body);` I am sending the JSON I paste at the beginning of the question. But if instead of `req.body` I put this XML with Dummy data `'<Dealers><Detail DealerName = "TESTING123" CardId = "1222" NickName = "tester123" Active = "1" LegalId = "16545" TypeId = "1"></Detail></Dealers>'` then everything works fine because the DB need to receive an XML.

So, what are your recommendations, what should I do to put the JSON data as a XML ?

Comment: So just `npm install` that library and use it there right? Then you can do `json2xml(req.body)`?

Comment: Have you got the solution of your problem?

Comment: @AmitGupta see the accepted answer by @ accraze below

Comment: grt. You can also have a look on [fast-xml-parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser) for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just load the `json2xml` library...

- install `$ npm install json2xml`
- import the module in your code: `var json2xml = require("json2xml");`

and then convert the json to xml like so:

```
var key,
    attrs=[];

for (key in req.body) {
    if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.key = req.body.key;
        attrs.push(obj);
    }
}

var dealerXml = json2xml({dealer:req.body, attr:attrs}, { attributes_key:'attr'}); 

request.input('Dealer_Param', sql.VarChar(1000), dealerXml);
```